# overriding the resulted rows, while pasting rows to destination sheet

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, overriding

The following code run perfectly which was suggested by a helpful user, but overwrites the result (rows) and displays only last copied rows to the destination sheet.
Please suggest modification in the code below:

```
Sub Selectrows()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim destSht As Worksheet

    Set destSht = Worksheets("VERTDEST") 

    With Worksheets("VERTALL")
     lastrow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
     For Each cel In .Range("H4:H" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)
       If cel.Value >= 2.5 Then cel.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(3, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(3)
       Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Snapshot [image: my sheet looks like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess its' because column A seems to be full of empty cells

hence target `End(xlUp)` to column D (i.e. column index = 4)

```
Sub Selectrows()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim destSht As Worksheet

    Set destSht = Worksheets("VERTDEST")

    With Worksheets("VERTALL")
        lastrow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        For Each cel In .Range("H4:H" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)
            If cel.Value >= 2.5 Then cel.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(3, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(3,-3)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```